# Realm file size is after calling deleteAll on Logout

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am using Realm for my application. On logout of the application I am using deleteAll on Realm but Realm file size is same as before logout.

What else I need to do before logout to delete all and reduce transaction size of the file.

Comment: A little code would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You should use Realm configuration called `shouldCompactOnLaunch`.

That's the link you looking for [Compacting](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#compacting-realms)

Compacting is equivalent of SQLite Vacuum function.

Sample code from docs

```
let config = Realm.Configuration(shouldCompactOnLaunch: { totalBytes, usedBytes in
// totalBytes refers to the size of the file on disk in bytes (data + free space)
// usedBytes refers to the number of bytes used by data in the file

// Compact if the file is over 100MB in size and less than 50% 'used'
    let oneHundredMB = 100 * 1024 * 1024
    return (totalBytes > oneHundredMB) && (Double(usedBytes) / Double(totalBytes)) < 0.5
})
do {
// Realm is compacted on the first open if the configuration block conditions were met.
   let realm = try Realm(configuration: config)
} catch {
// handle error compacting or opening Realm


}
```

Comment: I am already doing this, but I want to do the same on logout of my application. is there any way to do it.